# Construct JSON object from array on client-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a string array like this:

```
['QWJvdXQ=','SG93IGl0IFdvcmtz','SG9tZQ==','Q29udHJpYnV0ZQ==','Q29udGFjdA==']
```

What I want to do, is turn it into something like this:

```
[
   {
       "id" : "QWJvdXQ=",
       "url": "about.html"

   },
   {
       "id" : "SG93IGl0IFdvcmtz",
       "url": "how_it_works.html"

   },
   {
       "id" : "SG9tZQ==",
       "url": "index.html"

   },
   {

       "id" : "Q29udHJpYnV0ZQ==",
       "url": "contribute.html"
   },
   {
       "id" : "Q29udGFjdA=="
       "url": "contact.html"
   }
]
```

The attributes aren't the focus -- what I'm basically trying to do is make each item in the array an object with the value as an value of an attribute, and add another (or more) key-value pairs into those objects.

Right now, I'm trying to do this on the client-side, using jQuery and JS. I also am running node.js, so if this is easier to do on the server-side I'm open to any suggestions. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need

- [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`window.atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.atob)

all together;

```
JSON.stringify(
    ['QWJvdXQ=','SG93IGl0IFdvcmtz','SG9tZQ==','Q29udHJpYnV0ZQ==','Q29udGFjdA=='].map(
        function (e) {
            return {
                    'id': e,
                    'url': atob(e).toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '_') + '.html'
                   }; // I converted the string to URL as I expect you wanted
        }
    ),
0, 4);
```

Comment: +1 for deducing exactly what the transform from input to output was without the OP actually saying so.

Comment: +1, did'nt see this one, much nicer approach! Also, good eye for catching the base 64.

Comment: I've been working with this a lot recently -- it seems to return a string. (found this out through typeof). Is there a way for this to be an object?

Comment: Got this through $.parseJSON(string) for anyone whose wondering! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I thought you wanted a JSON string, by the output you gave (you didn't specify a type). Rather than converting to a string then back to an _Object_ / _Array_, you could just skip the two steps that effectively cancel eachother out - i.e. change `JSON.stringify( /* code */, 0, 4)` to `/* code */` and you'll have the _Array_ without converting to JSON; then you don't need to use `parseJSON`.